# Prove That A Function Defined By Lebesgue Integral Is Always Finite And Continuous

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on the Borel Sigma Algebra, and assume that $\mu (\mathbb{R}) < \infty$. I have to prove that: $$h(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin^2 (tx) e^{-x^2} \mu (dx)$$ is always finite for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and that it's continuous at every $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I feel like since the measure of $\mathbb{R}$ is finite, then the integral coming out to finite value should be obvious? But I don't know how to formally state it. An idea is that the function inside of the integral is less than or equal to $e^{-x^2}$ and then I show that integral is finite.

Also, for continuity, my idea is to show that the limit of $h(t)$ at $t$ exists and it equals the actual value. However, similar to the first case, I don't know how to actually calculate the value or the limit.

Does anyone have any hints/pointers?

Comment: The integrand is actually bounded by $1$. So the integral is finite and continuity follows immediately from Bounded Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  I understand the bounding - thank you! I don't quite get how Bounded Convergence Theorem applies though. Where does it say anything about continuity?

Comment: Continuity comes because we show that for any subsequence $t_n \to t$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} h(t_n) =h(t)$ for all $t$. However, @KaviRamaMurthy, the part I don't understand is that Bounded Convergence Theorem requires the functions to be simple. I don't believe any functions here are simple -- how do we work with that?

Comment: @sfs2007 I'm not sure why you say you need simple functions. The bounded convergence theorem (an obvious special case of dominated convergence) doesn't require this.